# react native with firebase phone auth validation failed

Tags: android, firebase, react-native

I'm trying to make react native with firebase phone auth through [react-native-firebase docs](https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v4.0.x/auth/phone-auth)
and I get this error

> Error: This app is not authorized to use Firebase Authentication. Please verifythat the correct package name and SHA-1 are configured in the Firebase Console. [ App validation failed ]

I have already created debug.keystore

```
keytool -genkey -v -keystore debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android -keyalg RSA -validity 14000
```

then I get the SHA1

```
keytool -list -alias androiddebugkey -keystore "C:\Users\adirz\.android\debug.keystore" -storepass android -keypass android
```

and paste into firebase console and download the google-services.json and add to my react native app.
then into my code I wrote

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  View,
  Button,
  Text,
  TextInput,
  Image,
  ActivityIndicator,
  Platform,
} from 'react-native';

import firebase from 'react-native-firebase'

const imageUrl =
  'https://www.shareicon.net/data/512x512/2016/07/19/798524_sms_512x512.png';

export default class PhoneAuth extends Component {
  static getDefaultState() {
    return {
      error: '',
      codeInput: '',
      phoneNumber: '+44',
      auto: Platform.OS === 'android',
      autoVerifyCountDown: 0,
      sent: false,
      started: false,
      user: null,
    };
  }

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.timeout = 20;
    this._autoVerifyInterval = null;
    this.state = PhoneAuth.getDefaultState();
  }

  _tick() {
    this.setState({
      autoVerifyCountDown: this.state.autoVerifyCountDown - 1,
    });
  }

  /**
   * Called when confirm code is pressed - we should have the code and verificationId now in state.
   */
  afterVerify = () => {
    const { codeInput, verificationId } = this.state;
    const credential = firebase.auth.PhoneAuthProvider.credential(
      verificationId,
      codeInput
    );

    // TODO do something with credential for example:
    firebase
      .auth()
      .signInWithCredential(credential)
      .then(user => {
        console.log('PHONE AUTH USER ->>>>>', user.toJSON());
        this.setState({ user: user.toJSON() });
      })
      .catch(console.error);
  };

  signIn = () => {
    const { phoneNumber } = this.state;
    this.setState(
      {
        error: '',
        started: true,
        autoVerifyCountDown: this.timeout,
      },
      () => {
        firebase
          .auth()
          .verifyPhoneNumber(phoneNumber)
          .on('state_changed', phoneAuthSnapshot => {
            console.log(phoneAuthSnapshot);
            switch (phoneAuthSnapshot.state) {
              case firebase.auth.PhoneAuthState.CODE_SENT: // or 'sent'
                // update state with code sent and if android start a interval timer
                // for auto verify - to provide visual feedback
                this.setState(
                  {
                    sent: true,
                    verificationId: phoneAuthSnapshot.verificationId,
                    autoVerifyCountDown: this.timeout,
                  },
                  () => {
                    if (this.state.auto) {
                      this._autoVerifyInterval = setInterval(
                        this._tick.bind(this),
                        1000
                      );
                    }
                  }
                );
                break;
              case firebase.auth.PhoneAuthState.ERROR: // or 'error'
                // restart the phone flow again on error
                clearInterval(this._autoVerifyInterval);
                this.setState({
                  ...PhoneAuth.getDefaultState(),
                  error: phoneAuthSnapshot.error.message,
                });
                break;

              // ---------------------
              // ANDROID ONLY EVENTS
              // ---------------------
              case firebase.auth.PhoneAuthState.AUTO_VERIFY_TIMEOUT: // or 'timeout'
                clearInterval(this._autoVerifyInterval);
                this.setState({
                  sent: true,
                  auto: false,
                  verificationId: phoneAuthSnapshot.verificationId,
                });
                break;
              case firebase.auth.PhoneAuthState.AUTO_VERIFIED: // or 'verified'
                clearInterval(this._autoVerifyInterval);
                this.setState({
                  sent: true,
                  codeInput: phoneAuthSnapshot.code,
                  verificationId: phoneAuthSnapshot.verificationId,
                });
                break;
              default:
              // will never get here - just for linting
            }
          });
      }
    );
  };

  renderInputPhoneNumber() {
    const { phoneNumber } = this.state;
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <Text>Enter phone number:</Text>
        <TextInput
          autoFocus
          style={{ height: 40, marginTop: 15, marginBottom: 15 }}
          onChangeText={value => this.setState({ phoneNumber: value })}
          placeholder="Phone number ... "
          value={phoneNumber}
          keyboardType = 'phone-pad'
        />
        <Button
          title="Begin Verification"
          color="green"
          onPress={this.signIn}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }

  renderSendingCode() {
    const { phoneNumber } = this.state;

    return (
      <View style={{ paddingBottom: 15 }}>
        <Text style={{ paddingBottom: 25 }}>
          {`Sending verification code to '${phoneNumber}'.`}
        </Text>
        <ActivityIndicator animating style={{ padding: 50 }} size="large" />
      </View>
    );
  }

  renderAutoVerifyProgress() {
    const {
      autoVerifyCountDown,
      started,
      error,
      sent,
      phoneNumber,
    } = this.state;
    if (!sent && started && !error.length) {
      return this.renderSendingCode();
    }
    return (
      <View style={{ padding: 0 }}>
        <Text style={{ paddingBottom: 25 }}>
          {`Verification code has been successfully sent to '${phoneNumber}'.`}
        </Text>
        <Text style={{ marginBottom: 25 }}>
          {`We'll now attempt to automatically verify the code for you. This will timeout in ${autoVerifyCountDown} seconds.`}
        </Text>
        <Button
          style={{ paddingTop: 25 }}
          title="I have a code already"
          color="green"
          onPress={() => this.setState({ auto: false })}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }

  renderError() {
    const { error } = this.state;

    return (
      <View
        style={{
          padding: 10,
          borderRadius: 5,
          margin: 10,
          backgroundColor: 'rgb(255,0,0)',
        }}
      >
        <Text style={{ color: '#fff' }}>{error}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }

  render() {
    const { started, error, codeInput, sent, auto, user } = this.state;
    return (
      <View
        style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: user ? 'rgb(0, 200, 0)' : '#fff' }}
      >
        <View
          style={{
            padding: 5,
            justifyContent: 'center',
            alignItems: 'center',
            flex: 1,
          }}
        >
          <Image
            source={{ uri: imageUrl }}
            style={{
              width: 128,
              height: 128,
              marginTop: 25,
              marginBottom: 15,
            }}
          />
          <Text style={{ fontSize: 25, marginBottom: 20 }}>
            Phone Auth Example
          </Text>
          {error && error.length ? this.renderError() : null}
          {!started && !sent ? this.renderInputPhoneNumber() : null}
          {started && auto && !codeInput.length
            ? this.renderAutoVerifyProgress()
            : null}
          {!user && started && sent && (codeInput.length || !auto) ? (
            <View style={{ marginTop: 15 }}>
              <Text>Enter verification code below:</Text>
              <TextInput
                autoFocus
                style={{ height: 40, marginTop: 15, marginBottom: 15 }}
                onChangeText={value => this.setState({ codeInput: value })}
                placeholder="Code ... "
                value={codeInput}
              />
              <Button
                title="Confirm Code"
                color="#841584"
                onPress={this.afterVerify}
              />
            </View>
          ) : null}
          {user ? (
            <View style={{ marginTop: 15 }}>
              <Text>{`Signed in with new user id: '${user.uid}'`}</Text>
            </View>
          ) : null}
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

/*
 { user ? (
 <View
 style={{
 padding: 15,
 justifyContent: 'center',
 alignItems: 'center',
 backgroundColor: '#77dd77',
 flex: 1,
 }}
 >
 <Image source={{ uri: successImageUri }} style={{ width: 100, height: 100, marginBottom: 25 }} />
 <Text style={{ fontSize: 25 }}>Signed In!</Text>
 <Text>{JSON.stringify(user)}</Text>
 </View>
 ) : null}
 */

// Example usage if handling here and not in optionalCompleteCb:
// const { verificationId, code } = phoneAuthSnapshot;
// const credential = firebase.auth.PhoneAuthProvider.credential(verificationId, code);

// Do something with your new credential, e.g.:
// firebase.auth().signInWithCredential(credential);
// firebase.auth().linkWithCredential(credential);
// etc ...
```

and I still get this error.

I generated sha1
[image]
then I copy in my project
[image]
I checked in AndroidManifest.xml I have the same packagename.

Comment: Have you actually enabled it in the console online though?

Comment: the sign in with phone? yes I enabled

Comment: You're using a physical device to connect, right?

Comment: Yes.Im using in physical device

Comment: Why your project has two SHA-1? @AdirZoari

Comment: I just try some times.. I found solution, I will publish it now

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I know that sometimes is a little bit annoying go to step by step again, but normally is the better way to find the error.

Don't know exactly the IDE that you are using, so I make this with android Studio, but you can copy to yours. Or import the Android project to do this in Android Studio

First go to your firebase console and check your package name
[image]

Now in Android Studio check if your package is really the same, inside AndroidManifest.xml
[image]

**If is not the same, you should change in firebase, even launch a new project**

Next step SHA-1

You can use exactly this code (don't need to change) `keytool -list -v -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android`

In Android Studio open the Terminal (View > Tool Windows > Terminal) and Copy/Paste

[image]
Copy the SHA-1 (suggest to save in some place)

Go to Firebase console settings (click on the gear)

[image]

Check the SHA-1
[image]

download the `google-services.json` again.

Put in the app folder (Delete the previous one)
You can see this in android studio using the "project" view

[image]

And what work for this question (copy from the question owner in a answer above)

You need to generate SHA1 from android studio when you run the project!

- Run your project.
- Click on Gradle menu where it on right-hand side.
- Expand Gradle Tasks tree.
- Double click on android -> signingReport and you'll see the result

For Android studio 2.2 - result will be available under Run console but use highlighted toggle button.

Comment: Hey, first thank you for your time and great explanation. I did exactly as you described before, it still show me same issue. I checked step by step. I generate debug.keystore with other commands because yours not works for me. I generate with  keytool -genkey -v -keystore debug.keystore -storepass android -alias androiddebugkey -keypass android -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000, then show the keystore with your command.

Comment: I'm using react native with IDE visual studio code. I edited my post and add the generate sha1 and photo from firebase console.. just asking, in your screenshot of sha1, i see it's version 1 and mine is version 3. what the version says?

Comment: @AdirZoari research a lot and did not found about this version =|. Maybe work it to create a new question! And thanks for the Right click. Will copy your answer in mine to be more correct.

Comment: thank you for your time. I will award your answer when it enable. I have 2 new issues with firebase firebase auth and fcm, if u have time https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50120751/firebase-auth-phone-not-send-sms-to-user-that-already-aunthenticated https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50087894/react-native-with-firebase-fcm/50124583#50124583

Comment: @AdirZoari I am getting the same issue. Tried everything mention in the approved answer but still its getting failed. And I too am getting `version 3`. How did you resolve your issue?

Comment: Hey @Canato i just follow all the steps but i see this message again `Error: [auth/app-not-authorized] This app is not authorized to use Firebase Authentication. Please verify that the correct package name and SHA-1 are configured in the Firebase Console.`

Answer (score 1):

If you use Android Studio you can connect Firebase to your account and set the dependencies automatically

Tools -> Firebase -> Authentication -> Link:"Email and password authentication" -> Step 1 and 2 (And follow the link in Step 2)

Comment: Hey roman, I'm using with react native with IDE vistual studio code

Comment: I guess you set the dependencies to use the google json file? [link](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/google-services-plugin)

Comment: Actually this is the best solution for me.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution
you need to generate SHA1 from android studio when you run the project!

1. Run your project.
2. Click on Gradle menu.
3. Expand Gradle Tasks tree.
4. Double click on android -> signingReport and you'll see the result

*For Android studio 2.2 - result will be available under Run console but use highlighted toggle button.*

Comment: Hey @AdirZoari I dont have in Android Studio "Gradle menu" ! , and error `Error: [auth/app-not-authorized] This app is not authorized to use Firebase Authentication` is gone when I write a phone number for a test in firebase console ! so my Q is when I release the app for production Firebase will send an SMS message with Code to users?

Answer (score 0):

If **everything is correct**

- package name
- SHA1 key
- firebase configuration

Certainly, that is because of the way you test.

You have to run the app on a real device then try again.