# firebase auth phone not send sms to user that already aunthenticated

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to implement phone auth with firebase in react-native app.
I just see that if user already signed up with phone number (exist in Authenticated table in firebase console) and he sign out and want to sign up again with the same phone, I don't get sms code again. I get verificationId null and it throws the errow

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null

in this line of code

```
  {started && auto && !codeInput && !codeInput.length
        ? this.renderAutoVerifyProgress()
        : null}
```

my full code

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  View,
  Button,
  Text,
  TextInput,
  Image,
  ActivityIndicator,
  Platform,
} from 'react-native';
import firebase from 'react-native-firebase';


const imageUrl =
  'https://www.shareicon.net/data/512x512/2016/07/19/798524_sms_512x512.png';

export default class PhoneAuth extends Component {
  static getDefaultState() {
    return {
      error: '',
      codeInput: '',
      phoneNumber: '+972',
      auto: Platform.OS === 'android',
      autoVerifyCountDown: 0,
      sent: false,
      started: false,
      user: null,
    };
  }

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.timeout = 20;
    this._autoVerifyInterval = null;
    this.state = PhoneAuth.getDefaultState();
  }

  _tick() {
    this.setState({
      autoVerifyCountDown: this.state.autoVerifyCountDown - 1,
    });
  }

  /**
   * Called when confirm code is pressed - we should have the code and verificationId now in state.
   */
  afterVerify = () => {
    const { codeInput, verificationId } = this.state;
    const credential = firebase.auth.PhoneAuthProvider.credential(
      verificationId,
      codeInput
    );

    // TODO do something with credential for example:
    firebase
      .auth()
      .signInWithCredential(credential)
      .then(user => {
        console.log('PHONE AUTH USER ->>>>>', user.toJSON());
        this.setState({ user: user.toJSON() });
      })
      .catch(console.error);
  };

  signIn = () => {
    const { phoneNumber } = this.state;
    this.setState(
      {
        error: '',
        started: true,
        autoVerifyCountDown: this.timeout,
      },
      () => {
        firebase
          .auth()
          .verifyPhoneNumber(phoneNumber)
          .on('state_changed', phoneAuthSnapshot => {
            console.log(phoneAuthSnapshot);
            switch (phoneAuthSnapshot.state) {
              case firebase.auth.PhoneAuthState.CODE_SENT: // or 'sent'
                // update state with code sent and if android start a interval timer
                // for auto verify - to provide visual feedback
                this.setState(
                  {
                    sent: true,
                    verificationId: phoneAuthSnapshot.verificationId,
                    autoVerifyCountDown: this.timeout,
                  },
                  () => {
                    if (this.state.auto) {
                      this._autoVerifyInterval = setInterval(
                        this._tick.bind(this),
                        1000
                      );
                    }
                  }
                );
                break;
              case firebase.auth.PhoneAuthState.ERROR: // or 'error'
                // restart the phone flow again on error
                clearInterval(this._autoVerifyInterval);
                this.setState({
                  ...PhoneAuth.getDefaultState(),
                  error: phoneAuthSnapshot.error.message,
                });
                break;

              // ---------------------
              // ANDROID ONLY EVENTS
              // ---------------------
              case firebase.auth.PhoneAuthState.AUTO_VERIFY_TIMEOUT: // or 'timeout'
                clearInterval(this._autoVerifyInterval);
                this.setState({
                  sent: true,
                  auto: false,
                  verificationId: phoneAuthSnapshot.verificationId,
                });
                break;
              case firebase.auth.PhoneAuthState.AUTO_VERIFIED: // or 'verified'
                clearInterval(this._autoVerifyInterval);
                this.setState({
                  sent: true,
                  codeInput: phoneAuthSnapshot.code,
                  verificationId: phoneAuthSnapshot.verificationId,
                });
                break;
              default:
              // will never get here - just for linting
            }
          });
      }
    );
  };

  renderInputPhoneNumber() {
    const { phoneNumber } = this.state;
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <Text>Enter phone number:</Text>
        <TextInput
          autoFocus
          style={{ height: 40, marginTop: 15, marginBottom: 15 }}
          onChangeText={value => this.setState({ phoneNumber: value })}
          placeholder="Phone number ... "
          value={phoneNumber}
        />
        <Button
          title="Begin Verification"
          color="green"
          onPress={this.signIn}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }

  renderSendingCode() {
    const { phoneNumber } = this.state;

    return (
      <View style={{ paddingBottom: 15 }}>
        <Text style={{ paddingBottom: 25 }}>
          {`Sending verification code to '${phoneNumber}'.`}
        </Text>
        <ActivityIndicator animating style={{ padding: 50 }} size="large" />
      </View>
    );
  }

  renderAutoVerifyProgress() {
    const {
      autoVerifyCountDown,
      started,
      error,
      sent,
      phoneNumber,
    } = this.state;
    if (!sent && started && !error.length) {
      return this.renderSendingCode();
    }
    return (
      <View style={{ padding: 0 }}>
        <Text style={{ paddingBottom: 25 }}>
          {`Verification code has been successfully sent to '${phoneNumber}'.`}
        </Text>
        <Text style={{ marginBottom: 25 }}>
          {`We'll now attempt to automatically verify the code for you. This will timeout in ${autoVerifyCountDown} seconds.`}
        </Text>
        <Button
          style={{ paddingTop: 25 }}
          title="I have a code already"
          color="green"
          onPress={() => this.setState({ auto: false })}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }

  renderError() {
    const { error } = this.state;

    return (
      <View
        style={{
          padding: 10,
          borderRadius: 5,
          margin: 10,
          backgroundColor: 'rgb(255,0,0)',
        }}
      >
        <Text style={{ color: '#fff' }}>{error}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }

  render() {
    const { started, error, codeInput, sent, auto, user } = this.state;
    return (
      <View
        style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: user ? 'rgb(0, 200, 0)' : '#fff' }}
      >
        <View
          style={{
            padding: 5,
            justifyContent: 'center',
            alignItems: 'center',
            flex: 1,
          }}
        >
          <Image
            source={{ uri: imageUrl }}
            style={{
              width: 128,
              height: 128,
              marginTop: 25,
              marginBottom: 15,
            }}
          />
          <Text style={{ fontSize: 25, marginBottom: 20 }}>
            Phone Auth Example
          </Text>
          {error && error.length ? this.renderError() : null}
          {!started && !sent ? this.renderInputPhoneNumber() : null}
          {started && auto && !codeInput && !codeInput.length
            ? this.renderAutoVerifyProgress()
            : null}
          {!user && started && sent && (codeInput && codeInput.length || !auto) ? (
            <View style={{ marginTop: 15 }}>
              <Text>Enter verification code below:</Text>
              <TextInput
                autoFocus
                style={{ height: 40, marginTop: 15, marginBottom: 15 }}
                onChangeText={value => this.setState({ codeInput: value })}
                placeholder="Code ... "
                value={codeInput}
              />
              <Button
                title="Confirm Code"
                color="#841584"
                onPress={this.afterVerify}
              />
            </View>
          ) : null}
          {user ? (
            <View style={{ marginTop: 15 }}>
              <Text>{`Signed in with new user id: '${user.uid}'`}</Text>
            </View>
          ) : null}
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: In this case maybe is a user experience, because you wanna to send SMS every time that user sign in? Would be better to do this only on registration. When he login or logout should not send again. Only if he deleted the account and register again, no?

Comment: it make sense.. so you suggest me to change the code, when I get not codeInput (when it now, show me codeInput.length is null) so the user already exist and not send him sms?

Comment: but what if I want to do like resend password or something like that?

Comment: Let's use chat https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170187/room-for-canato-and-adir-zoari

Comment: Were you able to resolve this problem? I have same problem where for some numbers I get state as 'Verified' and VerificationId and Code are Null. Now, how do I build Credential to use  firebase.auth()..signInWithCredential(credential)?

Comment: I also have this issue... @AdirZoari were you able to solve this?