# com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuthException: This app is not authorized to use Firebase Authentication.

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I cross checked everything SHA-1 is also correct as well as the packagename i am using real android device but still this error is showing.

`onVerificationFailed
                                                                    com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuthException: This app is not authorized to use Firebase Authentication. Please verifythat the correct package name and SHA-1 are configured in the Firebase Console. [ App validation failed. Is app running on a physical device? ]
                                                                        at com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzce.zzb(Unknown Source)
                                                                        at com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzdf.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                                        at com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzdg.run(Unknown Source)
                                                                        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6095)
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)`

here are the screenshots for SHA-1:
[image: SHA-1 from android studio]

[image: Firebase app settings]

[image: my package name]

my package name above

Comment: Did you figure what is wrong with this?? 
I am facing the same problem with a client. I might suggest that this should not be used in a emulator as it doesnt work in emulator

Comment: Try the detailed solution described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50085575/react-native-with-firebase-phone-auth-validation-failed), my problem was that after updating the SHA1 field, I failed to download and update the google-services.json file in my project.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue recently. If Your app was on the play store,I would have told you to add the SHA-1 provided by play store as well. But since it is just a debug mode.Make sure you have the recent SHA-1 as it can change based on some factors.

Comment: but i cross checked many its same, you know any reason it could be changed because once apk is installed how it can be changed

Comment: What to check the SHA-1 provided by the play store ?

Answer (score 0):

This issue only happened to my OPPO phone. I guess some Chinese phone manufactories root Android system so the phone is detected as a simulator?
Anyway, cope SHA-1 from google play to firebase works with me.

You can find google play SHA-1 from Google Play Console -> Release management -> App signing. 
[image: Where you can find signing SHA-1 from google play]

Just copy those SHA-1 to firebase.

For Firebase console. Go to "Project settings". You can find the place to paste SHA-1 from google play.
[image]

Answer (score -1):

Make sure SHA1 key in both playstore and firebase dashboard are same