# Firebase Authentication does not work in signed APK

Tags: firebase, authentication, apk, signed

I have implemented Google login with firebase auth service, it works fine when i an  using debugging app. But as when i generate signed apk. firebase auth does not login, please help!

[SHA1 in Firebase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iDaPq.png)

[SHA1 in Android Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3jEc0.png)

Comment: you need to take the SHA1 key using your key store file then add into firebase console it will be working fine!

Comment: I have checked SHA1 key from gradle and firebase is same, which has automatically uploaded at the time of firebase setup.... so will you please guide if i am doing something wrong

Comment: Refer this link : https://stackoverflow.com/a/15727931/3406577

Comment: sir i have edited my question where i have given pic of both my SHA1 from Firebase and Android Studio, Please let me know what to change ?

Comment: yes currently you're adding the android\debug.keystore it will only working for debug builds, but in live we need to take the SHA1 key based on your APK keystore file and add your console

Comment: follow the above link ( https://stackoverflow.com/a/15727931/3406577 )which i shared and create the SHA1 key using your live keystore file, problem will solved try that link

Comment: I have solved same issue by referring to this issue
https://stackoverflow.com/a/53133829/11216683

Answer (score 0):

The following steps can be used in order to solve the issue:

1. First check the package name , if it is same on firebase console as well as android studio, if not then make it same but if yes then
2. Generate SHA-1 :
   You can use exactly this code (no need to change), open terminal of android studio and paste this code:
   *keytool -list -v -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android*

and now compare it with SHA-1 present in the firebase console.

3. Clean and rebuild the gradle
   Hope the above mentioned steps could resolve the issue

Refer the link in order to get more clarity to the above mentioned procedure:
[react native with firebase phone auth validation failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50085575/react-native-with-firebase-phone-auth-validation-failed)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/21111624)

Comment: Kindly review the ans again if it is answered in a right manner now